# Spring Boot - Spring Security not working without enableautoconfig

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

In my spring boot application I am NOT using the @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation. With autoconfig not set, spring security as described [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) is not working. What do I need to do to enable spring security when autoconfig is not set.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application, [@EnableWebMvcSecurity](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-enablewebmvcsecurity) comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Create an implementation of [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-javaconfig-build/1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/api-reference/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) and register it in the implementation of your AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.

e.g.

```
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class<?>[]{MyWebSecurityServiceConfiguration.class, <your other configuration classes>};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return new Class<?>[]{<your mvc configuration class>.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[]{<your mapping here>};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
            return new Filter[]{new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain")};
    }
```

}